# Connect to redis from node js through local proxy

Tags: node.js, proxy

First: My node application should connect to Local Proxy.

Later - Redis connection should go through this proxy.

I am using global-tunnel-ng for connecting to proxy.
global-tunnel-ng works for "request"

But, its is not working for "redis.createClient" ..

Checked Redis monitor -- It is showing my localip ... not the Proxy Ip

Comment: Node-redis does not support proxy setting

Comment: @emptyhua so, how it achieve it?

Comment: Currently there is no way